# java.lang.String: length() vs. count?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a test string:

```
String test = "oiwfoilfhlshflkshdlkfhsdlfhlskdhfslkhvslkvhvkjdhfkljshvdfkjhvdsköljhvskljdfhvblskjbkvljslkhjjssdlkhdsflksjflkjdlfjslkjljlfjslfjldfjjhvbksdjhbvslkdfjhbvslkjvhbslkvbjbn";
```

During debug I noticed following. When I print out the length:

```
System.out.println("Test length() : " + test.length());
```

returns

> Test length() :  166

When I debug, I can read 333 as **count** for test variable.

[image]

**What does the count represent?**

Comment: You should mention what version of Java you're using as the `count` field doesn't exist in Java 11 (or at least I can't find it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String implementation contains an array of chars - **value**. So **count** field in some implementations is used for calculation of the array's declared size.

One could notice that the **count** value provided differs the given String length twice - this looks like a hint to ASCII/UTF-8/UTF-16 divergence as per 1 Unicode (UTF-16) symbol is represented by 2 bytes in a String instance.

An example:

```
String str = "f";
str.length(); // 1
str.getBytes().length; // 1
```

but

```
String str = "ў";
str.length(); // 1
str.getBytes().length; // 2
```

See also:

- [Apache String Implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)
- [Android String Implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/fullsdk/sources/android-28/+/master/java/lang/String.java)

What JDK are you using? It may bring more light on what exactly your count is.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The references to `count` are  `public String(char value[], int offset, int count) ` and another similar one. Both are short lived, constructor parameters.

Comment: After String object creation, they are gone, cannot see then in debugger.

Comment: No offence intended, but you don't seem to understand what I mean. In OP's image, there is also a field name `shadow`. Can you find this one in String doc too?

Comment: @EugenCovaci shadow is related to dalvik's GC

Comment: Probably so is `count`, that's my point. The constructors with count as argument **do not get called** when declaring `String test = "bla bla"`.

Comment: I think count represents the original byte reservation for the string (2 bytes per character), and then one for the terminator. However: Java immediately takes traditional ASCII chars back down to one byte following this reservation as an optimization step. See Anto Hlinisty's experiment with getBytes().length

Comment: Wait, so you just found a method parameter that has the same name as a private field in an unknown JRE and declared them the same? And for reference you provide an old JDK implementation with a completely different meaning of that private field? (Note, that very implementation you link has `public int length() {return count;}`, so it wouldn't show any of the behaviour in the question) How did this get so many upvotes?

Comment: "(UTF-16) symbol is represented by 2 chars": A Java `char`, `Character` and `String` element are indeed 1 UTF-16 code unit, which takes 2 bytes. Saying chars causes confusion.

Comment: @DanielSchmidt Are you sire there is a terminator? Why would one need that if we have a content length field?

Answer (score 3):

When asking [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) Java-related questions, always mention that as there are some *major* differences.

The android ART runtime optimizes `java.lang.String` by compressing the normally two-byte Java chars into single-byte ASCII strings when possible. You can see it in the source of [`java.lang.String`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/fullsdk/sources/android-28/+/master/java/lang/String.java#569):

```
public int length() {
    // BEGIN Android-changed: Get length from count field rather than value array (see above).
    // return value.length;
    final boolean STRING_COMPRESSION_ENABLED = true;
    if (STRING_COMPRESSION_ENABLED) {
        // For the compression purposes (save the characters as 8-bit if all characters
        // are ASCII), the least significant bit of "count" is used as the compression flag.
        return (count >>> 1);
    } else {
        return count;
    }
}
```

String compression is specified in the [native code as](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/mirror/string.h#35):

```
// String Compression
static constexpr bool kUseStringCompression = true;
enum class StringCompressionFlag : uint32_t {
    kCompressed = 0u,
    kUncompressed = 1u
};
```

This flag is [OR-ed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/mirror/string.h#221) with the `count` value:

```
static int32_t GetFlaggedCount(int32_t length, bool compressible) {
    return kUseStringCompression
        ? static_cast<int32_t>((static_cast<uint32_t>(length) << 1) |
                               (static_cast<uint32_t>(compressible
                                                          ? StringCompressionFlag::kCompressed
                                                          : StringCompressionFlag::kUncompressed)))
        : length;
}
```

When loading strings from the constant pool, however, string compression is not performed. Hence you get a doubling of the original char count + 1 (333 = 166 * 2 + 1). That additional 1 is the "uncompressed" flag.